# Override to read local JS-file in web app wrapper

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

Im looking into creating a web wrapper for a existing web app. I clearly want to make it as quick as possible.

Is it possible to host the JS-files locally, instead of having to download the file, without altering the existing web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a WebViewClient you can prevent loading the javascript from the web server (**edit** only in API level 11 and higher unfortunately). Or you can disable JavaScript, load the page, then enable JavaScript again. After the page is loaded you can modify the DOM using javascript: urls to load the scripts from a local url (like file:///android_asset from the top of my head).

You can also change the cache strategy of the WebView so that it will never fetch anything that is already fetched once before, which might also be what you want in this case. These are set in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html, you could set it to LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK in this case.

Comment: For tweaking the cache settings (which is the least hacky solution) you should look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html The other approach is just to disable javascript when loading the page (using the same settings) and then inject javascript to load the scripts you want when the page has loaded.